# Differentiating composition or under a change of variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $u(x,y)$ and I want to differentiate $u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))$ with respect to, say, $x$. I have seen both of the following notations being used for that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u_x(\xi,\eta)\xi_x+u_y(\xi,\eta)\eta_x$$
or
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u_{\xi}(\xi,\eta)\xi_x+u_{\eta}(\xi,\eta)\eta_x.$$
My impression is that they are both the same, but I wanted to check. If these are not the same, does it depend on whether $u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))$ is obtained from $u(x,y)$ by either a change of variables or a composition? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I significantly prefer the latter notation, the first one being read verbatim is incorrect. $u_x$ is shorthand for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ but that is exactly what we are calculating so if taken literally its clear that

$$ u_x(ξ,η)ξ_x+u_y(ξ,η)η_x$$

Is not what is meant, rather what they are saying is

$$ "\text{differentiate by first argument}" \xi_x + "\text{differentiate by second argument}" \eta_x $$

Which is correct

Now the latter notation makes this explicitly clear since the first argument of $u$ of $\xi$ and the second argument of $u$ is $\eta$ by clearly stating

$$ u_ξ(ξ,η)ξ_x+u_η(ξ,η)η_x$$

Now if you loved the first notation somehow, what you can do, which in my opinion is just as clear is state

$$ \partial_1 u  \times \xi_x + \partial_2 u\times \eta_x$$

This reads explicitly as "differeniate by" the subscript (1 or 2)'th argument, and then multiply the derivative of the expression.

Comment: I think $u_x(\xi,\eta)$ is understood as $u_x(x,y)\circ(\xi,\eta)$, otherwise it makes no sense. And I think what we want to do is apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to $u(\xi,\eta)$, which is not just $u_x(\xi,\eta)$. For example, it is easy to see that if $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $\xi=e^{x+y}$ and $\eta=e^{x-y}$, then                 both $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u_x(\xi,\eta)\xi_x+u_y(\xi,\eta)\eta_x$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))=u_{\xi}(\xi,\eta)\xi_x+u_{\eta}(\xi,\eta)\eta_x.$$
yield the same result. I guess it all comes down to preference.

Comment: @user210190 yes, but that implicit change of variables is what I don't like. Unless the notation can encode that it's I think preferable to avoid introducing these stray "x's" and "y's". Of course you can always figure it out with an effort from the context, but given how difficult some ideas in math can be by themselves, why murk it up with unnecessarily subtle notation. This of course is entirely opinion on syntax, so I am no more correct than those who disagree with me

Comment: Indeed. I guess is no secret that even notation in math can make your head spin.